# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in unit test for class genereted using WSDL

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, soap-client

I am consuming a SOAP web service successfully. Now, I am trying to write some unit tests but when the test access the class (EmployeeInfo) generated using WSDL then it is giving following error.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc.<clinit>(TypeDesc.java:61)
    at com.www.soapservice.schema.EmployeeInfo.<clinit>(EmployeeInfo.java:106)
```

The unit test I wrote is as follows

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RecordsManagerTests {

    @Mock
    private SoapClient soapClient;

    @Test
    public void sampletest() {
        Mockito.when(soapClient.getFullEmployeeInfoById(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(new EmployeeInfo());

        RecordsManagerImpl sut = new RecordsManagerImpl(soapClient);

        sut.getEmployeeInformation(999);
    }

}
```

I searched for this issue but only could find mocking the service.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why its working but it is, I added following line at the start of the test method and its working

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl");
```